# programs that can't run parallely

Tags: python, parallel-processing, shared-libraries, static-analysis

I am building a python program to initiates the same program (`benchmark_program` in this example) with different parameters and then examine the results.

To improve efficiency I invoke several subprocess from `multiprocessing.Pool` to run each command in parallel. Then the weird thing is: however core number (number of parallel subprocess) increase (still below the physical core number and all cores are available), the total test time remians constant and from `htop` I found that everytime the script executes, only 1 core is actually engaged (IO is not busy either).

At first I thought it's a python problem so I wrote a simple program `compute_primes` to do some heavy computation on 1 single cores, and parallelizing does improve performance.

So I guess there is something in `benchmark_program`, perhaps some libraries, that can be invoked/called by only 1 cpu at a time. Now my question is: what makes a program that can't be run parallely? Is it some shared libraries or dependences?

the test script:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess
import time


def invoke_subprocess(arg):
    #command = "benchmark_program {}".format(arg)
    #command = "compute_primes {}".format(arg)

    command = "sleep 0.5"

    return subprocess.run(command,
                          shell=True,
                          check=True,
                          stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).returncode


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for num_core in [2, 4, 8, 16]:
        start = time.time()
        with Pool(num_core) as p:
            collected_result = p.map(invoke_subprocess, range(16))
        print("core-{} took {:.2f} second".format(num_core,
                                                  time.time() - start))
```

This is basically the parallel script. You get the original program when commenting `command = "sleep 0.5"` and uncomment `#command = "benchmark_program {}".format(arg)`

Comment: This is a rather broad question. There can be many reasons which prevent a parallel execution, e. g. I/O operations on the same storage medium by multiple processes.

Comment: @MichaelButscher not a IO problem (forgot to mention)

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is: what makes a program that can't be run parallely?

Any number of things:

- the program can bind itself to a single CPU using [sched_setaffinity](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_getaffinity.2.html)
- the program can use [flock](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) to lock a file and prevent other executions of itself
- the program can create a semaphore to achieve the same
- the program can create a "lock file", and the second execution could wait until that file is removed. The file could also be a unix domain socket, or a named pipe.

There are probably tens of different mechanisms which could be used to prevent concurrent execution. You can use `strace` to figure out what the program *actually* does, and go from there.